# Why are my self-hosted fonts being fetched twice?

Tags: performance, debugging, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, webfonts

[image: Problem illustrated in Chrome DevTools]

My problem is as illustrated in the above picture, where we can see a set of two font files being fetched and transferred twice.

These fonts are self-hosted for my Gatsby.js site, and this double-fetching leads me to see font flashes twice on page load. Some clues that might shed some light:

1) Lighthouse is complaining about this error being logged into the console:

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED" with regards to one of the fonts (Open Sans).

2) The initiator for the second set of font requests is "other". A google search tells me that "other" refers to requests made from a user (which seems unlikely here since this is on page load) or for preloaded requests (I didn't explicitly include a preloaded link in my HTML head, but maybe one of those Webpack scripts?).

3) This issue only appears in my production build. It works okay and only fetches once in development mode.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this, or could perhaps give me some advice as to how I might even begin to debug this problem?

Comment: Do you have any ajax request that returns content and you inject it in the dom? If yes, that's one reason.

Comment: @Konstantinos Nope, no dynamic aspects to the site at all.

Comment: Interesting challenge. Note the load time difference as well — the second load is nearly a quarter of the first. What happens when you do a "Find in Files" whatever editor you're using?